# textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: is passing a nil argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfielddelegate

As the title mentioned, I have a `UITextField` and am using the `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` delegate method.

I got a crash log from a user because the string argument passed in `replacementString` is `nil`. Of course I can simply do a `nil` check to avoid the crash but I wonder why the string is `nil` in the first place.

Could anyone think of a reason for the string to be `nil`? I tried to delete characters and all but couldn't reproduce the case.
If that may help, users are mainly Japanese. I thought it could be a unicode issue, without success.

Information about the crash log:

- User is using iOS 11.2.
- Source code is in Objective-C. What surprised me is that according to the Swift doc, the passed argument should not be `nil`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield
- Code crash with

`-> description: *** -[__NSCFString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument`.

And the actual code looks like this:

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                             withString:string];

   ... some other code...

    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Could you show the crash log?

Comment: I edited the question with the code.

Comment: I wonder if this helps: https://gist.github.com/niw/931a64c0dd78bd805912